# rxjs typescript error Argument of type

Tags: typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

I have such code taken from the rxjs sample:

```
 Observable.fromEvent(this.getNativeElement(this.right), 'click')
      .map(event => 10)
      .startWith({x: 400, y: 400})
      .scan((acc, curr) => Object.assign({}, acc, {x: acc.x + curr}))
      .subscribe(position => this.position = position);
```

Typescript giving such error:

```
[ts] Argument of type '{ x: number; y: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number | Scheduler'.
       Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'x' does not exist in type 'number | Scheduler'.
```

How to fix that?

Comment: You've mapped all emitted events to a number literal - `.map(event => 10)` - so each time an event fires, the observable will emit `10`. (Why?) TypeScript has then correctly inferred the `Observable<number>` type, but you've then specified a non-number starting value, which is why the error is effected.

Comment: @cartant it is just an example I am looking at. Is there a better way of doing that to avoid an error?

Comment: @sreginogemoh What he's saying is that your example does not make sense. The error you are getting is legitimate. How can an observable of numbers start with an object that is not a number? There is a logical error in what your code is saying, and typescript is pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can always force TypeScript to ignore type checks by type casting to `any`. In your case this could be:

```
.map(event => <any>10)
```

Btw, there's a [`mapTo()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-mapTo) operator to convert all items to a constant value.